# There is no smoke in render view instead it scatters outside the domain in blender 2.9 Eevee render

Tags: physics, smoke-simulation

I started to make smoke simulation, I saw some tutorials to do that. I can see the smoke in solid view but not in render view instead I can see the color of the smoke outside the domain. I did this project in blender 2.9 Eevee. I couldn't fix the problem.

This is in solid view (https://i.stack.imgur.com/wcUbR.jpg) This is in render view (https://i.stack.imgur.com/v1FQ6.jpg)

Node setup (https://i.stack.imgur.com/FL6rj.jpg)enter image description here

Here is the blend file.
[image]

Comment: Hello, and welcome. you don't have to make a new topic for the same question. You just need to edit the original one and ask for the question to be open again

Comment: I voted to close for Emir reason ... BTW I don't have your issue under 2.93 eevee ... it is brighter but still visible. Change background (world) color to black ... probably just display intensity?

Comment: I changed but smoke and fire is not inside the domain. Please help.

Comment: Please ... change your original post https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/223698 and ask to reopen as suggested with proper screenshots as suggested ... anyway according to your blend file - since I can't reproduce issue (fire out of domain) I can't help anyway ... try start a new file from scratch or different version of blender.

Comment: Instead of having users go through links and external sites please use the builtin tools to embed images in your post. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491)

Answer (score 1):

i downloaded your blend file.

I raised the resolution division to 64 (which is already low - but 32 is too low).

I checked adaptive domain.

I tapped on "bake all".

Result (Rendered view):

[image]

if you want more smoke, go to shader editor and increase density:

[image]

then you get:

[image]

more density:

[image]

more smoke:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply and answer. I did what you said in the answer but the fire and smoke scatters all over the render view port. I used blender 2.9

Comment: Did you try it with a newer version?

Comment: Yes, I tried with a new version even I tried in blender 2.8. I think so there must be volumetric problem. The smoke and fire is not inside the domain in render view. This happens only for smoke and fire simulation. This problem is not found in volumetrics in lights.

Comment: honestly...i never heard or read of such a problem. I am not sure but i think it could be your computer/graphic card...i just tried out with 2.83 -> works

Comment: Hi, I think so vdb modifier not working. Is there anything to turn on?

Comment: It's vdb problem even I imported vdb fire I can't see anything in the render view in blender 2.9

Comment: Please could you fix this